# How to restrict WebSocket server connection to only one?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

For creating WebSocket server I have used [Java-WebSocket](http://java-websocket.org/) library. It looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/48MjTtUa), and it is working.

But now I wish to upgrade, so server can have only one active client connection.
Is there some kind of option for doing this, or should I check all connections, and close all, non-first active, connections?

I have tried that like this:

```java
@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake)
{
    System.out.println("WebSocketServer::onOpen()");

    boolean first = true;
    Collection<WebSocket> con = this.connections();
    synchronized(con) {
        for (WebSocket c : con) {
            if (first && c.isOpen()) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this closes all connections, and kills Websocket server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a counter outside the onOpen() method, and initialise it to 0.
Then in the onOpen() method, check if the counter is 1. If it is, close the connection `conn`, otherwise increment the counter.

Comment: No, this will not work, since the problem is a little bigger. If I close all connections in `onOpen()` method (aka: deny all connections), WebSocket server is killed (first it is runned onError, then onClose, then onError again).

Comment: Maybe it is because you close a socket that is not open yet?

Comment: How do I check that? If we find out, how to deny all connections, I will then know how to close specific one, or to close all but specific one...